# Iterate a mysql resultset which has 10000 rows, it takes 3.5 seconds. Is it normal?

Tags: c++, mysql, database-performance, mysql++

I use C++ and mysql++ to get a resultset and iterate it with fetch_row()

The resultset has 10000 rows, this "While" Loop took nearly 3.5 seconds.(I have comment out the content in while loop.)

is this situation normal? 
I thought it should completed much faster!

```
Connection* conn = ConnPool::getSingletonPtr()->getConn();
Query qr = conn->query(sql);

SYSTEMTIME lpsystime;  
GetLocalTime(&lpsystime);  

UseQueryResult res = qr.use();
while(FryRow row = res.fetch_row())
{
    /*
    MyObject obj;
    for(int i=0; i<row.size(); i++)
    {
        obj.setValue(res.fetch_field(i).name(), row[i]);
    }
    objList->push_back(obj);
    */
}

GetLocalTime(&lpsystime);
```

MyObject has properties:

```
 int procedureNo;
 int index;
 int employeeNo;
 int procCount;
 int state;
 int procPermission;
 int procDeadline;
 int advanceAlert;
 DateTime procTime;
 int resultFlag;
 string comment;
 int flowDirection;
 int isHideComment;
 int isTrack;
 DateTime arriveTime;
 string preNodesJsonStr;
 string nextNodesJsonStr;
 string attachStr;
 string employeeName;
 DateTime employeeBirthDay;
```

****************************Spliter*******************************
Thank you guys! I modified the code and measured the time again like this:

```
Connection* conn = ConnPool::getSingletonPtr()->getConn();
Query qr = conn->query(sql);

SYSTEMTIME lpsystime;  
GetLocalTime(&lpsystime);  // get the time before use().

UseQueryResult res = qr.use();

GetLocalTime(&lpsystime);  // get the time before While loop.


while(FryRow row = res.fetch_row())
{
        /*
        MyObject obj;
        for(int i=0; i<row.size(); i++)
        {
            obj.setValue(res.fetch_field(i).name(), row[i]);
        }
        objList->push_back(obj);
        */
}

GetLocalTime(&lpsystime);  // get the time when While loop finished.
```

**the use() function only costs 10 ms.**

**ant the While loop costs 1.677 seconds.**

**If I don't comment out the content in while Loop. It costs 3.386 seconds.**

The setValue() function is defined as below:

```
MyObject::setValue(const char * colName, const mysqlpp::String& ele)
{ 
 if(strcmp(colName,"column010") == 0)
      procedureNo = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column020") == 0)
      index = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column030") == 0)
      employeeNo = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column040") == 0)
      procCount = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column050") == 0)
      state = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column060") == 0)
      procPermission = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column070") == 0)
      procDeadline = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column080") == 0)
      advanceAlert = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column090") == 0)
      procTime = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column100") == 0)
      resultFlag = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column110") == 0)
      comment = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column120") == 0)
      flowDirection = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column130") == 0)
      isHideComment = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column140") == 0)
      isTrack = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column150") == 0)
      arriveTime = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column160") == 0)
      preNodesJsonStr = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column170") == 0)
      nextNodesJsonStr = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column180") == 0)
      attachStr = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column190") == 0)
      employeeName = ele;
 else if(strcmp(colName,"column200") == 0)
      employeeBirthDay = ele;
}
```

Comment: How fast a `fetch_row` is depends on the amount and kind of data the row has, but are you sure it is the while loop and not the query itself?

Comment: Get all rows in single query please. Server is dying.

Comment: @Tuğrul: I guess he does get the rows from a single query.

Comment: How long does that actual query take? Perhaps you need some indices.

Comment: @t.niese I modified the question description. The query costs 20ms, but when i iterate the resultset, it takes a long time. please give me some more advice! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you also measure the execution time of your query. `conn->query(sql);` does *not* execute the query. It just builds a `Query` object. The `use` method then actually executes the query. I.e., in your code, this line actually executes the query:

```
UseQueryResult res = qr.use();
```

From the mysql++ documentation:

```
 UseQueryResult mysqlpp::Query::use ()
```

> Execute a query that can return rows, with access to the rows in sequence.Use one of the use() 
>   overloads if memory efficiency is important. They return an object
>   that can walk through the result records one by one, without fetching
>   the entire result set from the server.

But note that even if you pull the `use` call out, you might still get some query execution time in your loop, because `use` pulls the rows one by one. Consequently, the database executes the query tuple by tuple and only computes the next tuple when you take it from the result. If you really want to measure a loop through all of the results, you must use the `store` function instead. It executes the query thoroughly and stores the result in a block of memory. Then, your loop will be blazingly fast. However, you should still prefer `use` because first storing all results into memory is usually just a waste of time and memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I measured the time consuming again.the use() function only costs 10 ms.
and the While loop costs 1.677 seconds.
If I don't comment out the content in while Loop. It costs 3.386 seconds. I modified the question and added some description. Please have a look. Best Wishes!

Comment: @zackchen: Read my last paragraph. The problem is that mysql executes the query "tuple at a time", i.e., when you call `next`, then one tuple is produced by the query. So the query is not executed once, it is executed partly whenever you want a new tuple. So I still think the problem is the query. Try using `store` instead of `use`, then your while loop will be extremely fast, but the `store` call will be expensive instead.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I tried again and use the Store. the function res = qr.store() costs 1.11 seconds, means it costs 1.11 seconds to load the 10000 tuples into memory, isn't it? and then the while loop costs 2.55 seconds. Orz. Then after the while loop, the HeapFree costs more than 40 seconds....

Comment: Considering your while loop: You have two problems here: First is that you use only strings, even for parameters that are ints or dates. This incurs high casting costs and all the strings clutter up your heap. Next, you do a lot of string comparisons which are expensive as well. Since you already know in which order the columns are stored in the row, (e.g., you know that the first column will be column010) you should set them directly instead of checking column names.